# How to make Window Title font upper-case?

Tags: fonts, window

I would like to know if it is possible to make it so that the window title font in Ubuntu is always displayed as uppercase. For the font I want to use, lowercase does not look nice. Thank you!

Comment: I think that will depend on your Window Manager, whichever that is.

Comment: In theory you could use a font which only has upper-case letters...depends on your WM, too (if you can change the font, that is).

Comment: I am using Unity on 12.04, so my Window Manager is compiz then?

Comment: Would it be in compiz then?